# Oracle regex substring

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I am trying to get the value between two semi colons.

```
select (REGEXP_SUBSTR(col,'[^:]+',1,2,null)) from test
```

These are the rows I am dealing with:

```
1236:10:EXEC
1236::EXEC
```

In my result set, I want to get:

```
10
<null>
```

The query above returns:

```
10
EXEC
```

Comment: Use `REGEXP_SUBSTR(s,':([^:]*)',1,1,null,1)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can avoid regexp for this; for example:

```
select substr(col, instr(col, ':') +1, instr(col, ':', 1, 2) - instr(col, ':') -1)
from test
```

How it works:

```
select instr(col, ':') as firstColon,
       instr(col, ':', 1, 2) as secondColon,
       instr(col, ':', 1, 2) - instr(col, ':') -1 as lengthOfResultingString,
       substr(col, instr(col, ':') +1, instr(col, ':', 1, 2) - instr(col, ':') -1) as result
from test
```

gives:

```
FIRSTCOLON SECONDCOLON LENGTHOFRESULTINGSTRING RESULT
---------- ----------- ----------------------- ------------
         5           8                       2 10
         5           6                       0
```

This assumes that you always have at least two colon characters in the string.

With regexp, in a slower, but more compact way, you could use:

```
regexp_substr(col, ':([^:]*):', 1, 1, null, 1)
```

Comment: Thanks. That was great

Answer (score 0):

```
with test (col)  as
(
  select '1236:10:EX' from dual union all
  select '1543::Ex' from dual
)
select regexp_replace(col, '(:(.*):)|.', '\2') from test;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use regexp_substr like this to handle NULL list elements.  The 4th argument is the element in the list you want:

```
with test (col) as
(
  select '1236:10:EX' from dual union all
  select '1543::Ex' from dual
)
select regexp_substr(col, '(.*?)(:|$)', 1, 2, NULL, 1) from test;
```